# Adding a tag target

Tags: php, twig

I want to add a robots meta tag, if I have:

```
/cars/?q=bmw
```

in url, and don't add it, if I have just

```
/cars/opel
```

How can I do this in twig?

```
{% block additional_meta_tags %}
    $fullPuthName = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    if (fullPuthName) {
        <meta name='robots', content='noindex'>
    }
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Why would you even start this by assembling the full URL, including host name and protocol? These are in no way relevant to the decision to begin with. `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` will either be `/cars/?q=bmw`, or it will be `/cars/opel`. Assuming proper URL encoding was used everywhere, checking whether or not this contains a question mark should theoretically be enough here already.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get `q` query parameter:

   ```
   {% set q = app.request.get('q') %}
   ```
2. Make a conditional decision:

   ```
   {% if q|length %}
       <meta name='robots', content='noindex'>
   {% endif %}
   ```